# How to disable "Sec-Fetch-Mode" ,"Sec-Fetch-Dest:" header by command-line flag

Tags: google-chrome

How to disable "Sec-Fetch-Mode" ,"Sec-Fetch-Dest:" header by  command-line flag
I want to disable this headers in my chrome application

[image]